# Parallel.ForEach loop is not working "it skips some and double do others"

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have 2 methods that can do the work for me, one is serial and the other one is parallel.
The reason for parallelization is because there are lots of iteration(about 100,000 or so)
For some reason, the parallel one do skip or double doing some iterations, and I don't have any clue how to debug it.

The serial method

```
for(int i = somenum; i >= 0; i-- ){

    foreach (var nue in nuelist)
    {
        foreach (var path in nue.pathlist)
        {
            foreach (var conn in nue.connlist)
            {
                Func(conn,path); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The parallel method

```
for(int i = somenum; i >= 0; i-- ){

    Parallel.ForEach(nuelist,nue =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(nue.pathlist,path=>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(nue.connlist, conn=>
            {
                Func(conn,path);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Inside Path class

```cs
Nue firstnue;
public void Func(Conn conn,Path path)
{
    List<Conn> list = new(){conn};
    list.AddRange(path.list);
    _ = new Path(list); 
}
public Path(List<Conn>)
{
   //other things
   firstnue.pathlist.Add(this);
   /*
   firstnue is another nue that will be 
   in the next iteration of for loop
   */
}
```

They are both the same method except, of course, `foreach` and `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

the code is for the code in [here](https://github.com/2a34-cmd/Programming-ANN/tree/Visual-Studio-version) (GitHub page)

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: Just a guess, but could it bee, that your `Path.NewPathsParallel()` method adds or removes items either from `layerList` or `layerList[i].neuronList`? If something is skipped or done double, it seems your index gets out of sync, cause you manipulate a list while you use it.  What happens, if you replace your for-loop with `foreach(var foo in layerList.Reverse())`? Do you get an exception because you change the list, while iterating it?

Comment: -Oliver No, it doesn't. I thought about that. the beginning loop is ```for``` in both ways, so this problem you wrote don't happen

Comment: *"where func here is constructing more paths"* -- Do you mean that the `Func(conn,path);` adds items in the `nue.pathlist`?

Comment: -Theodor Zoulias No, it doesn't. I meant that in the body of ```Func()```, there is ```new Path()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [sedat-kapanoglu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54937/sedat-kapanoglu), I found the problem is really about thread safety. The solution was to change every `List<T>` to `ConcurrentBag<T>`.

For everyone, like me, The solution of "parallel not working with collections" is to change from `System.Collections.Generic` to `System.Collections.Concurrent`

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>`, which I assume you use with `firstnue.pathlist`, isn't thread-safe. That means, when you add/remove items from the same `List<T>` from multiple threads at the same time, your data will get corrupt. In order to avoid that problem, the simplest solution is to use a lock, so multiple threads doesn't try to modify list at once.

However, a lock essentially serializes the list operations, and if the only thing you do in `Func` is to change a list, you may not gain much by parallelizing the code. But, if you still want to give it a try, you just need to change this:

```cs
firstnue.pathlist.Add(this);
```

to this:

```cs
lock (firstnue.pathlist)
{
  firstnue.pathlist.Add(this);
}
```